# Thymeleaf select dropdown not populating full Java object

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following code with Thymeleaf and Spring. For some lists that I have the value of the selected option populates the entire object however for some it does not.

```
public class BeneficiaryUploadCommand {

    private List<SchemeCommand> schemeCommandList;

    private List<BudgetHeads> budgetHeadsList;

    @NotEmpty
    private List<BeneficiaryType> beneficiaryTypeLists;

    @NotEmpty
    private List<FinancialYear> financialYearList;

    @NotEmpty
    private List<SubSchemes> subSchemesList;

    private Date toDate;

    private Date fromDate;

    @Size(min=10, max = 10)
    private String toDate1;

    @Size(min=10, max = 10)
    private String fromDate1;

    @NotEmpty
    private List<BenefitType> benefitTypesList;

    @NotNull
    private Integer beneficiariesProposed;

    @NotNull
    private Double stateShare;

    private Double actualExpenditure;

    @NotNull
    private Double advancedExpenditure;

    @NotNull
    private char aadharLinkedOrNot;

    @NotNull
    private char cropItemDataAvailable;

    @NotNull
    private String schemeCommandId;

    @NotNull
    private String budgetHeadsListId;
}
```

Thymeleaf code is as follows:

```
        <select id="financialYearListId" th:field="*{financialYearList}" style="width:100px; float:left;" >
            <option th:value="0" th:text=" Select "></option>
            <th:block th:each="finYear : ${beneficiaryData.financialYearList}">
                <option th:value="${finYear.id}" th:text="${finYear.financialYear}" label=" - Select - "></option>
            </th:block>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td colspan="1" align="right"><font color="red">*</font>
        <b>From Date</b>
    </td>
    <td colspan="1">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{fromDate1}" name="from_date"  class="date form-control" style="width: 100px; margin: 0px;"/>
    </td>
    <td colspan="1" align="right"><font color="red">*</font>
        <b>To Date</b>
    </td>
    <td colspan="1">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{toDate1}"  name="to_date"  class="date form-control" style="width: 100px; margin: 0px;"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="1"><font color="red">*</font> <b>Scheme</b></td>
    <td colspan="1" width="20%">
        <select th:field="*{schemeCommandId}" name="scheme_id" style="width:250px" th:onchange="'getSubSchemesandBudgetHeads(this.value);'">
            <th:block th:each="scheme : ${beneficiaryData.schemeCommandList}">
                <option th:value="${scheme.id}"   th:text="${scheme.schemeName}" label=" - Select - " />
            </th:block>
        </select>
```

Now when I select the `th:field="*{financialYearList}"`
the entire `financialyear` object of the `List` object is populated. However with `schemeCommandList` it only gives the id? I am confused how can some objects be converted whole whereas some it only provides the id.

Answer (score 0):

The difference seems to be that, for the 'financial year' dropdown, your Java class has:

```
private List<FinancialYear> financialYearList;
```

which corresponds to the following Thymeleaf markup:

```
<select id="financialYearListId" th:field="*{financialYearList}"...
```

However, the 'scheme command' dropdown, has the following markup:

```
<select th:field="*{schemeCommandId}"...
```

which is populating the Java field:

```
private String schemeCommandId;
```

In other words, the Thymeleaf markup is telling the first dropdown to populate the `financialYearList` field, where the second one is only telling it to populate the `schemeCommandId` field, and that seems to be the effect you're seeing.

So, I imagine the solution to get what you want would be to change the Thymeleaf markup for the second dropdown to be:

```
<select th:field="*{schemeCommandList}"...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it with the *{schemeCommandList} field I get a conversion exception. Why does it work for some and not for some? Its very unstable

Comment: It's definitely not unstable! The problems you are encountering will be in your understanding of how to use it! You'll need to compare the differences between your `FinancialYear` class and your `SchemeCommand` class to identify why one works and one doesn't. The 'conversion exception' will be telling you that it's unable to convert the value you select into a `SchemeCommand`. It's probably giving you a specific reason about why it's failing - edit your post to include that, and, if necessary, the two classes, and someone might be able to point out your error.